# Implementing Parse.com push notification in unity for android platform

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add push notification from parse.com in my unity project for android platform. 
But I am having a hard time understanding and getting started with parse.com push notifications. The parse.com documentation for unity for android is hardly of any help and does not cover proper steps to take to make a push notification successfully. I want to send a message(push notification) from my parse.com dashboard console window to a registered device.

The issues i am having are as follows:

- How to register a android device?
- How to generate a device token for android device?
- How to check for applications installation on android device and pass it to parse.com
- I am unable to get/generate the device token.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what all steps should be taken to implement push notifications of parse.com for android device.

I even searched for some video tutorials for the same and even tried some demos but no luck with those too.

Note: I know parse.com is retiring their services by Jan 28, 2017.

Comment: Parse just support old customer and they have also provided migration guide to those account holder. They will soon stop supporting them. So you should now try using some other service, there are many tutorial on GCM, Please look at those and try using them

Answer (score 0):

As Parse.com announced `The Parse hosted service will be retired on January 28, 2017.` And also they have given a migration guide to the people who already used the parse.com services.

So you should not use parse services. Instead I recommend you to use Google Cloud Services with your own web service. Recently I found [this nicely explained article about GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/) from androidhive.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea. parse is going to shutdowns very soon.
I recommend you to use onesignal push notifications service.They have SDK for unity & It is totally free and has many options to segment user's based on your interest. 
They find revenue by collecting your user data by analytics.
I use onesignal and it's good. (Recommending you to have a good privacy policy regarding PII)
https://onesignal.com/